# data is not shared - Intent chooser on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent-chooser

I am trying to share data in social sited like Facebook, WhatsApp, Google+, Twitter every site is sharing data only Facebook isn't. Why facebook does not share data on their wall

I am using this code below:

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hello guys this testing");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"hey");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

How do I share data on Facebook?

Comment: You have to use facebook shareContentDialog to share data.

Comment: Saritha G i want use only intent chooser any way shareContentDialog  is allow text with link....

Comment: Yah..ShareContentDialog can also allow you to add text message and link. Share is diff for facebook, so you should use it instead of using intent share.